# Script to covert between Cuddle and Allman indent styles?

Tags: indentation, braces

I believe it is called "cuddle" style:

```
function foo() {
   // blah
}

function foo() 
{
   // blah
}
```

Does anyone know of any scripts that will go through a file and toggle in one direction or the other?  My goal is TextMate integration through a bundle, but any script in any language should be fine.  I believe I can hook most any language into textmate through a bundle.

Comment: Just for the record, the first one is called K&R Style ( Kernighan and Ritchie), the second one is called Allman Style.

Allman is the true indentation style.

Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.bierkandt.org/beautify/ is how I solved this.  I made a new bundle in Textmate of

```
/path/to/php ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/beautifyphp/beautify_php -i 5 -v 0 -l -b 0
```

Now all I do, is select my chunk of php, run the bundle command, and it will reformat it to my liking.  It does other nice things, like align equals as well.  Granted, align equals is something you can do with the "source" bundle in TextMate already.

The only downside is that it shoves in a "made pretty with phpBeautify" or something like that at the bottom, but it is a quick delete.  I am sure I could strip it inside the bundle, but this work is not something I do that often.

Answer (score 2):

You might get away with using [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/), though it doesn't specifically support JavaScript, it's loose enough that `astyle -b` does format your example correctly.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I love this.  I usually prefer to use vim to most IDEs, so this saves me the trouble of having to fix brace styles by loading all the code I'm working with into an IDE that I'm not actually going to use.

Answer (score 1):

Switching indentation styles is a form of pretty-printing or code beautifying.

For Javascript, the online tool at http://jsbeautifier.org/ also has the code available for download.

For other languages, there's a comprehensive list of code beautifiers on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prettyprint

You can script TextMate with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CSS bundle in TextMate as it does a very similar thing when you press C-q